# Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, cors

I am trying to build a meal planning app (with a shopping app on top of it) and right now the one issue that has been perplexing me from the start is the CORS policy blocking my API requests. The entire message is as follows:

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?f=a' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."

I am trying to make a fetch request from themealdb (a free, open-source meal API) and while postman/insomnia is bringing up the request just fine, I once even got it working, but I don't know how or why, and then it just stopped.

I've tried to fiddle around with the access-control-allow-headers to allow it to accept anything (using '*') but that did nothing. It is really frustrating and I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I clicked on the network tab in the developer tools and while the console tells me I am getting that error as well as an Axios network error (probably linked to the CORS blocking) the actual network tab is telling me that everything is OK. With a status 200 on the preflight. The headers on the network request even show "Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization" under the request headers, so I don't know what the problem is.

I actually used a different api (from spoonacular) that did solve the problem, but a different problem arose from that API in a different place, and it has limited daily use which makes it difficult for me to debug since I only have so many attempts in a 24 hour period to do anything.

Any help? How do I allow the requests to go through so I can finally call it a day on this project?

this is my server code:

```
const express = require('express');
require('./database')
const userRoutes = require('./userRoutes');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express()


express()
  .use(cors())
  .use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
  .use(express.json())
  .use(userRoutes)
  .listen(8000, () => {console.log('Server running on port 8000.')})
```

I cannot use app.use(cors()) because if I do that, it'll break the code, and I won't be able to log in on my site.

Edit: I refactored my code to use app.use for everything... It now looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
require('./database')
const userRoutes = require('./userRoutes');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express()

app.use(cors({
  origin:'*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Authorization'
}))
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(userRoutes)
app.listen(8000, () => {console.log('Server running on port 8000.')})
```

Comment: `I've tried to fiddle around with the access-control-allow-headers` ... did you try to add the specific header that is causing the issue? i.e. `authorization` ... the *error* tells you exactly what the issue is - (you did make this change on the server, right?) - as for `even show "Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization"` - of course, since your request requires that header - for a better idea of what you're doing wrong, please post your client (browser) code, and your API server code, specifically where you "fiddle around with access-control-allow-headers"

Comment: I have an image of it here: https://imgur.com/a/4afu5rt    I really tried my best to work it out, but I just couldn't find a solution. I have the code on the right hand side (I have a two-monitor setup) and no matter what I do, it just won't work. Server side I do use cors, but I did not touch that, do I need to put the headers there?

Comment: I also did try to add that header and all other headers to accept a '*' to mean to allow everything with no exceptions. But that did nothing. It is very frustrating because I did some other projects (a weather app) with another API that gave no trouble whatsoever. This is giving me trouble.

Comment: `I have an image` try posting CODE in the question - the image is unreadable

Comment: `I also did try to add that header and all other headers to accept a '*' to mean to allow everything` in the server code, right

Comment: `access-control-request-headers: "*"` - browser adds request headers for you, so, you don't need to do that (and `*` is not valid anyway) - I suspect you don't understand CORS

Comment: If you download the image, you will be able to see it at full resolution. Sorry for the inconvenience. I did look up the documentation for CORS and even saw a few videos on it, but nothing I did from those is making it work. It is really getting frustrating. I did attempt to put it in the server, but I am not sure if I am doing it right... I am using express... so in my 'express().use(cors({headers:{"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*"}})' would this be correct? Because I did this and it had no effect. using only the access-control-allow-headers: * does nothing either.

Comment: `If you download the image, you will be able to see it at full resolution` if you *add the code to the question* then the code will be readable

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *` is only possible *for requests without credentials* [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers#directives) - documented too is the fact that *the Authorization header can't be wildcarded and always needs to be listed explicitly* - not sure what documentation on CORS you've read, but your issue is clearly because you didn't read the right documentation

Comment: I added the server code.

Comment: where are you adding the allowed headers on the server code?

Comment: The `cors()` defaults allow any requested headers so you should not need to set anything manually

Comment: Remove `Access-Control-Request-Headers` from your request headers. Your browser will set it automatically in the preflight `OPTIONS` request if required

Answer (score -2):

I managed to solve this problem. I actually still don't know why the CORS behaved as it did, but I replaced my axios request with a simple fetch request and it resolved the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).